# How to load a location into the trap vector table LC3

Tags: lc3, lc3-trap

An assignment asks to load the location of a trap we were asked to write into location x0026 of the trap vector table. I understand loading into a register, but I'm not sure as far as loading something into the trap vector table. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is load your trap call as a separate .obj file into the simulator before you load your program.

This creates a new trap call for x26

```
.orig x26
    .fill x5000
.end
```

This means when you use TRAP x26 in your program it will run whatever code you have saved at x5000

Comment: Is there any way to do this within the same .obj file?

Comment: I've been trying to find a good way to do that but I don't think the standard LC3 editor supports the pseudo-opcode ".EXTERNAL" I've tried without luck. But you can just combine all of your code into one file, unless it's for a trap vector table entry.